# How to create image buttons that activate jQuery/js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd need to have like buttons inside tr elements to do js/jQuery things when clicked.

Strangely I'm having a hard time finding good knowledge on how to execute jQuery/js from inline html/image button.

Here's what I had in mind:

first create a custom function for the like button

```
  jQuery.fn.likebutn = function(theword, wordnumber) {
  
  //check if button is lighted up and if it is break


  //change button to lighted up
  jQuery(this).attr("src", "http://i46.tinypic.com/n18g3q.png");
  
  //add word to a div element
  jQuery('#cntrldiv0').append("<p>theword<p>");
  
  //ajax like.php file with the word and username/id
  jQuery.post('like.php', {theword:theword, userid: userid});
  };
```

then dynamically insert the function call and it's parameters (as the table is being created in PHP) in the image button element (so inline in html)

```
likebutn({theword: ${'row' . $wordnumber}, wordnumber:$wordnumber});
```

Which outputs

> likebutn(theword:foraminated, wordnumber:1)

for example.

So how do I evoke the function like that from html?

And on a side note, why is there so much event listening in jQuery/js image buttons I'm seeing when surfing the web (instead of what I'm suggesting), isn't that slower than evoking inline in html?

Here's how the construct would look: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc64R/

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I didn't =O I mean about the noConflict, what's the point of noConflict then? Anyhow the use of jQuery instead of just $ is kind of a personal choice of mine as I'm working with a lot of php. But perhaps when I ready my code for publication I'll just "replace all" jQuery with $ in all documents.

Comment: Well it's more to write for you and harder to read for pretty much everyone that is used to `$`. The point of `noConflict` is to not use `$` as a global variable. Inside the closure of the anonymous function `$` is fine - it does not interfere with whatever else uses the global `$`.

Comment: I see. I'll keep it in mind =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a variable called foraminated, this is incorrect:

```
likebutn(theword:foraminated, wordnumber:1)
```

should be:

```
likebutn(theword:"foraminated", wordnumber:1)
```

from html:

<... onclick="jQuery(this).likebutn(...)">

Comment: I think you are commenting on reference that was provided as output, not markup?

Comment: @Gavriel Oh! Somehow I almost missed your answer, thanks for correcting my little mistake there, you know I hear all kinds of bad stuff about the $ preceding every variable in php, but little mistakes like this one are harder to make in php if you ask me.
I'll accept your answer after I test it tomorrow.

Comment: oh, almost forgot, eventually I used `<a onclick="$('#lbtn0_1').likebutn('foraminated', '0');"><img id="lbtn0_1" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" alt="" src="images/likebutnp.png"></a>`